# Understanding RxJS BehaviorSubject

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, behaviorsubject

We try to use BehaviorSubject to share API data across multiple components. On my component I am triggering a HTTP request and updating the subject once the response is returned.

component.ts

```
onClick() {
    this.service.getCompanies();
    this.service.companiesList$.subscribe(companies => {
        console.log(companies.length); // 0 and then 1
    });
}
```

service.ts

```
companiesList$ = new BehaviorSubject([]);

getCompanies() {
    return this.http.get(myUrl).subscribe((res: any) => {
        this.companiesList$.next(res.data);
    });
}
```

How can I access only the last emitted value from the BehaviourSubject once the request is finished?

Comment: As some of the replies have implied, you don't need to wrap the Observable provided from an HTTP call in another Observable (the `BehaviorSubject`). You already have an Observable you can work with. Consider trying a declarative approach to your Observables. That will make notifications easier. See this for more information: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z76QlSpYcck

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the you could try the following, save the observable of the http request in the service and apply a shareReplay(1) operator on it. Then in your component(s) you can use it like the following:

component.ts

```
onClick() {
    this.service.getCompanies().subscribe(companies => {
        console.log(companies);
    });
}
```

service.ts

```
$companies =  this.http.get(myUrl).pipe(shareReplay(1));

getCompanies() {
    this.companies$;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

While technically you could use `companiesList$.getValue()`, I'd recommend not to create a subscription in your component using `subscribe()`, and use `AsyncPipe` instead ([ref](https://angular.io/api/common/AsyncPipe)). It could look like that:

component.ts

```js
companies$ = this.service.companiesList$.asObservable();

onClick() {
  this.service.getCompanies();
}
```

component.html

```html
<div *ngIf="companies$ | async as companies">
  <!-- your stuff -->
  {{ companies.length }}
</div>
```

Comment: I don't want to list companies on the template. I want to access the API companies through companiesList$ behaviourSubject AFTER receiving the result

Comment: Then you can do something like `this.service.companiesList$.pipe(skip(1)).subscribe(companies => {console.log(companies.length); });`. BehaviorSubject has an initial value (in this case `[]`), if you `skip` it, you should always have the most recent value in the subscribe. If you don't need the initial value, you could also consider using `ReplaySubject` or even `Subject` instead.

Answer (score 0):

To get the last emit value use:

`companiesList$.getValue()`.

If you what to use it within the stream use the [`withLatestFrom` operator](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/combination/withlatestfrom)

Answer (score 0):

I think what the answers here are missing is that you are using a BehaviourSubject, which is the wrong type of subject.

In short :

- A Subject will output values only from the time you subscribe. So if emit is called on a Subject 5 times, then a component subscribes, they won't see those previous 5 emits.
- A ReplaySubject will output X amount of values immediately when you subscribe. So if I have a ReplaySubject(1), and I output a value 5 times, then a component subscribes. They will *immediately* receive the last 1 value, then they will continue to receive further emits.
- A BehaviourSubject is almost identical to a ReplaySubject except it has a *default* value that will always be emitted, regardless of whether you have called emit on the subject.

In your code you have :

```
companiesList$ = new BehaviorSubject([]);
```

So even before you call emit, anyone who subscribes to this will immediately receive an empty array. So I think reading between the lines of your question, you are having issues receiving an empty array when you subscribe, *then* you are receiving your actual data.

You can resolve this by using a ReplaySubject :

```
companiesList$ = new ReplaySubject(1);
```

Which will output nothing until the first emit, then any subscribes will always receive this "last" emit.

It's worth learning the differences of each type of Subject here : https://tutorialsforangular.com/2020/12/12/subject-vs-replaysubject-vs-behaviorsubject/